# Getting an "Unresolved reference" error for an editText id in main activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I have just started Android Development with a basic app which takes the username and display in Toast but came across an error in the main activity. It says "Unresolved references: editName". I tried making the app again, manually importing editText widget and changing the id name but nothing works.
It would be great if someone can tell me what's going wrong.
[ScreenShot of the code with error underlined with red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWNKA.png).... [Module build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J0dQ.png).... [Project build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxgGX.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you the example in Java.

You must create a variable in your activity class

```
EditText editName;
```

then you must override the onCreate() method of the `Activity` class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
}
```

overriding the `onCreate()` you can take a reference to your EditText.

Answer (score 0):

If you're following a tutorial, they're probably expecting you to use Kotlin Synthetic Binding which means you need this in your `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

That will automagically create variables for each `View` in the layout that has an ID assigned - so if you have an `EditText` with an ID of `editName`, then a `val editName: EditText` will be created in the background when you inflate the layout. Yes it's magic, yes it trips everyone up and accounts for a lot of the problems people run into on here!

Savatore's answer is the normal, standard, non-magical way of doing it. If you want the convenience, look into the `View Binding` library, which is the official way of automatically binding views to variables (Kotlin synthetics are deprecated)

Comment: I think these plugins are already there (images added above). Please suggest what else might go wrong.

Comment: add ``import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*`` to your imports in the activity. But first try putting the text cursor over the red ``editText``, press ``Alt+Enter`` and see if it imports it for you (or offers to) - you very rarely have to add ``import`` lines yourself